# What does the [keys] tag mean?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Tag [keys](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/keys) seems to be in use for various things. What should be retagged?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Key" seems to mean quite a few different things. Good catch, <s>it would involve a lot of manual retagging though</s> doesn't matter anymore though :P

Let's see:

#### Keyboard keys

Both the physical ones on the keyboard and the conceptual ones like hotkeys, key-combos, and keystrokes that perform functions. Mostly in combination with [keyboard](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/keyboard), [keyboard-shortcut](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/keyboard-shortcut), [keyboard-layout](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/keyboard-layout), [hotkeys](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/hotkeys).

#### Registry key

The ones used in Windows Registry. Mostly in combination with [registry](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/registry).

#### Cryptographic keys

Encryption keys as in PGP. Mostly in combination with [php](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/php) or [cryptography](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/cryptography).

SSH keys generated by `ssh-keygen` tool. Mostly in combination with [ssh](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ssh).

#### Database keys

Keys as used in databases. Mostly in combination with [odbc](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/odbc), [access](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/access), etc.

#### Serial numbers

CD keys, product keys, serial numbers, et. la. Mostly in combination with [registration](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/registration) or [activation](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/activation).

Answer (score 4):

Based on the 12 questions it was on, seems utterly unnecessary to me.

It is now burninated.

[image: tag burninated]

Comment: Huh, weren't there like over 100 questions tagged `keys`? http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/keys

Comment: uhhhh, only 12? I recall seeing over 100 when I had a quick glance at the tag (when this question was posted)...

Comment: @dma well, not any more. Based on the sampling I saw, and the fact that once I deleted it only *one* question was [tag:untagged] .. I stand by the burnination.

Comment: f/e, I was just looking at the "questions tagged" number, didn't bother having a detailed look. I imagine a lot were accidentally split composites anyway (command key, license key, etc) and it's pretty useless as a tag, so I've no problems with the tag being gone. :).

Comment: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fsuperuser.com%2Fquestions%2Ftagged%2Fkeys - One hundred and seven, as of July 15ᵗʰ, 2011.

Comment: Um, Jeff, [one of your questions](http://superuser.com/questions/278951/my-keyboard-has-no-media-keys-can-i-control-media-without-them) seems to have had that tag [recently](http://i.stack.imgur.com/lVLJT.png).

Comment: @syn [tag:keyboard] seems sufficient, don't you think?

Comment: Don’t ask me; I didn’t add the `keys` tag to your question in addition to the `keyboard` tag (actually, I'm [not sure](http://superuser.com/posts/278951/timeline) [who did](http://superuser.com/posts/278951/revisions)).